# How does Blazor know when to look for a parameter change

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Let's say I have the following two comboboxes (all pseudo code):

```
<ComboBox Data="@AllLastNames" @bind-Value="@LastName"/>
<ComboBox Data="@AllFirstNames" @bind-Value="@FirstName"/>
```

And the code behind is:

```
private string LastName { get; set; }
private string FirstName { get; set; }

private List<string> AllLastNames => _allLastNames;
private List<string> AllFirstNames => _firstNameDictionary[LastName];
```

Ok, the above will all work great **if** Blazor will, at the appropriate times, get `AllFirstNames`, see that it has changed via a reference equality comparison, and calls `SetParameteraAsync()` with the new value.

So when/why and **how** does Blazor decide to check that `Data=` properties to see if they have changed?

Is this a case where, inside the `LastName` setter, I should call `StateHasChanged()`?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem?  Because at first glance this should work already, as posted. When it doesn't then expand the code to a [mre]

Comment: Well, a `List` is a reference type, and when you change members of the list, you don't actually change the reference.  So while you feel you've done something significant, you will have to notify the component that it needs to re-render itself.  For example, if you have another component modifying the items in your `List`, but are not changing the value of the ComboBox, Blazor may not know that anything has changed.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 This does change the list returned by AllFirstNames so that is a reference change. Now if I was changing the contents of AllFirstNames instead of returning a new list, then that would be an issue.

Comment: Changing a member in the current list or the reference to the list is irrelevant.  You need to build in a mechanism to trigger a component render when a mutation occurs.  Only when the render occurs will the Renderer will make the necessary checks to see if any child components are affected and notify them accordingly.   The component itself will render based on the component state at the instance the renderer runs the submitted `RenderFragment`,

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Correct me if I'm wrong, but selecting an item in the LastName ComboBox is a mutation - correct? That appears to be firing off a rendering and the `AllFirstNames ` getter is called, populating the firstname ComboBox.

Comment: Yes.  But changing the value isn't what kicks off the render, it's the UI event handler associated with the mutation.  See a previous answer [I think I gave you, but maybe it was someone else!] where I described the `ComponentBase` implementation of `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync`.  If my memory is failing me (rather traumatic experience at the dentist this afternoon), I'll put another answer up to elaborate on that.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis First off, sorry about the dentist (I hate going there too). Second, that's what I meant - that ComboBox re-renders as a response to the mouse click selecting a new element in its list. Is it that re-render by the ComboBox that kicks it off?

Comment: Correct on both counts.  In your example the parent treats the Bind setter in `@bind-Value` as a UI event so when it's called it triggers a render of the parent.  If either `data` has changed, it will be transmitted to `ComboBox`  when `SetParameteraAsync` is called.

Comment: You never dreamed components would be this complex when you started using Blazor!  Net8.0 has ratcheted up that complexity with render modes.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis yeah - every time I think I'm starting to really understand it, there's another nuance that I clearly was not understanding. And the new render modes - gonna have to learn those. As always, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when/why and how does Blazor decide to check that Data= properties to see if they have changed?

Every time that this component is rendered, and that should happen when LastName changes.

`Data="@AllFirstNames"` is a 'complex parameter' in Blazor, meaning it will always treated as changed.

Answer (score 2):

There's no black magic involved.

When the renderer instantiates a component, it creates and maintains a list of the mapped properties for that component.  It generates the `ParameterView` object from this list when it calls `SetParametersAsync`.

When the Renderer renders a component, it checks to determine if the state has changed on any  sub-component parameters.  If they have, it calls `SetParametersAsync` on the sub-component.

Note I state: "It calls `SetParametersAsync`", not "it renders the component".  If the component is a `ComponentBase` component then it will.  There are other Third Party Component Library components that may override `SetParametersAsync` and implement different logic that doesn't trigger a `StateHasChanged`.

The algorithm applied to each value to detect a change is as follows:

```cs
public static bool MayHaveChanged<T1, T2>(T1 oldValue, T2 newValue)
{
    var oldIsNotNull = oldValue != null;
    var newIsNotNull = newValue != null;

    // Only one is null so different
    if (oldIsNotNull != newIsNotNull)
        return true;

    var oldValueType = oldValue!.GetType();
    var newValueType = newValue!.GetType();

    // HERE
    if (oldValueType != newValueType)
        return true;

    if (!IsKnownImmutableType(oldValueType))
        return true;

    return !oldValue.Equals(newValue);
}

private static bool IsKnownImmutableType(Type type)
    => type.IsPrimitive
        || type == typeof(string)
        || type == typeof(DateTime)
        || type == typeof(Type)
        || type == typeof(decimal)
        || type == typeof(Guid);
```

Basically it can detect changes in primitives and some value objects.  For everything else `MayHaveChanged` returns `true` [it takes no chances].  Note callbacks and RenderFragments are reference objects, so return `true`.

In your case `List<string> AllLastNames` is a reference type so fails the test and `MayHaveChanged` returns `true`.  So if the parent component of `ComboBox` renders, the renderer will call `SetParametersAsync` on `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

How and why Blazor decides to update the state can be considered magic or a black box ([more about states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server)).

But if you are interested in what cases it works, I can give the following examples.

The state is updated **automatically**:

- On Blazor Event Handlers (@onclick, @bind- etc.)
- On [Component Lifecycle Events](https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/understanding-the-blazor-component-lifecycle) (`OnInitialized`, `OnParametersSet`, `ShouldRender`, `OnAfterRender`, etc.)
- On Razor Markup Update

You need to update the state **manually**:

- Async Operations (receiving data from API, database, file, etc.)
- Non-Blazor Events
- Interop with JavaScript

In your case `@bind-Value="@LastName"` works as a trigger to automatically update the state, for example when the user selects an item in the `ComboBox` `AllLastNames`, the entire chain is updated, i.e. `LastName`, `AllFirstNames` and `ComboBox` `AllFirstNames` without calling `StateHasChanged`.

Notes:
This is my personal preference, but from my experience, using a dictionary without checking the existence check can lead to an error, and it is often difficult to find the source.

I would suggest checking for existence (even if you are sure that it exists):

```cs
private List<string> AllFirstNames => _firstNameDictionary.TryGetValue(LastName, out var firstNames) ? firstNames : new List<string>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer (gave you an up vote). And you're correct on the dictionary check, I was keeping it simple for the purposes of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler e.g. OnChange to your combobox that will update reference list with new data from the database or some other source that you are using